# Firestore: How to dedupe documents returned by multiple firestore.Client().collection

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In my Python code, I am getting multiple documents from Firestore (I need to perform OR but it is not supported so instead running separately and combining them):

```
db = firestore.Client()

docs1 = db.collection("test").where(column1, '>=', value1)
docs2 = db.collection("test").where(column2, '>=', value2)
docs3 = db.collection("test").where(column3, '>=', value3)
```

Here I am not sure how to combine docs1, docs2 and docs3? When I printed the type, it said "generator" object or something. How can I dedupe them?

Comment: Consume each of the generators and add the documents to a dict, where the key is `doc.id`. Also read up a little bit about Python generators (for your purpose, you can think of them as iterators).

Comment: Thanks. That's the approach I took.

Comment: I have a script I wrote for this purpose. I'd like to post it as an answer, but the first non-working draft was AI-generated and there's a strict fascist ban on any and all code that may have even 1 character of it generated by AI or that was written on the same computer that once used AI or was used to read articles about AI. So instead, you can find it here: https://pastebin.com/8Z70bZwe